# Looping over PDF's to create dataframe

Tags: r, loops, pdf

I'm trying to loop over multiple PDF's and combine them using rbind. Right now I have this:

```
for (i in 1:length(all_pdfs)) {
   docket <- pdftools::pdf_text(all_pdfs[[i]]) %>%
     as.tibble() %>%
     mutate(month = as.character(d$docket_month[[i]]))
  }
```

where all_pdfs is a list of PDF's. However, docket is only returning the first PDF as a dataframe. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you're rewriting `docket` in every loop iteration

Answer (score 0):

You could try building docket out into a list and then un-listing the list.

```
docket <- list()
for (i in 1:length(all_pdfs)) {
          docket[[i]] <- pdftools::pdf_text(all_pdfs[[i]]) %>%
          as.tibble() %>%
          mutate(month = as.character(d$docket_month[[i]]))
       }

docket <- unlist(docket)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to merge PDF files with R, but if you have Python installed, you can use the code below tom merge all PDF files into one file.

```
# pdf_merger.py

import glob
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

def merger(output_path, input_paths):
    pdf_writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for path in input_paths:
        pdf_reader = PdfFileReader(path)
        for page in range(pdf_reader.getNumPages()):
            pdf_writer.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(page))

    with open(output_path, 'wb') as fh:
        pdf_writer.write(fh)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    paths = glob.glob('C:/your_path/*.pdf')
    paths.sort()
    merger('pdf_merger.pdf', paths)
```

https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2018/04/11/splitting-and-merging-pdfs-with-python/